# using ajax to upload multiple files

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I have a simple form which allows the user to upload comment text and files to the server. When the form is submitted, the file upload process is handled in 'upload.php' file. It works perfectly fine for uploading only 1 file.

I would like **my script** to be able upload  multiple files with AJAX.

This is what I did so far -

HTML (part of it):

```
<input type='file' name='file[]' maxlength='1' accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" />
<input type='file' name='file[]' maxlength='1' accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" />
<input type='file' name='file[]' maxlength='1' accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" />
```

and so on...I don't know how many files will be upload in advanced. users have script that allows them to upload as many they want to.

JS

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('submit','form',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 

    var $form = $(this);
    var file_data = $form.find('.file-field').prop('files')[0];   
    var form_data = new FormData();       
    form_data.append('act', act);
    form_data.append('comment[text]',  $form.find('.comment-field').val());   
    form_data.append('comment[pageName]',  $form.find('.pagename-field').val());   

    form_data.append('file[]', file_data);



    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "ajax/addComment.php",

           dataType: 'text',  
           cache: false,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,  
           async: false,
           data: form_data,
           success: function(data)
           {
                $("#loader").hide();
                $('#commentsBox'+$form.find('.refid-field').val()).prepend(data);
                 $("form").reset(); 

           }

         });

    return false; 

    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, roi, your upload.php file is also required to understand that have you used the loop to check that $_FILES have one file or multiple. More...you need to check what is sent by form_data javascript varibles.

Comment: @MarmikBhatt - hi,  I will be ok if upload.php will receive the files. i just have problem to transfer them to the server side...

Answer (score 0):

Here you get the contents of the file associated with the first file input.

> ```
> var file_data = $form.find('.file-field').prop('files')[0];
> ```

and a few lines later (these would make more sense being in adjacent lines) you put that data in the form data object:

> ```
> form_data.append('file[]', file_data);
> ```

Just use a `for` loop and replace the `0` with the loop iteration variable.

Comment: can u please help me with the "for" loop inside the script?

Comment: What's the problem? You're just looping over an array (or at least something close enough to an array that it makes no difference), and that's JavaScript 101.

Comment: problem if i don't familiar enough with the js syntax... :/ I'm use to work on the server side...

Comment: btw - why I can't tag your name (@Quentin)